# Having Difficulty getting Mongodb to work with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have installed mongodb on a newly installed Ubuntu 18.04 server, and while I am able to work with mongo on the command line, I cannot seem to connect to it using PHP.

I've been following the process as per https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQcQ5tvb5E8&t=620s:

apt install mongodb-server
apt install php-pear # to get PECL
apt install php7.2-dev # to get phpize
pecl install mongodb

phpinfo() shows **extension_dir=/usr/lib/php/20170718**, and mongodb.so is indeed in that directory, with the same ownership and permissions as all other files. **php -i | grep extension_dir** shows **extension_dir => /usr/lib/php/20170718 => /usr/lib/php/20170718**

I then added **extension=mongodb.so** to **/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini**, in the same location as the other extensions are listed. There is also a php.ini file under **/etc/php/7.2/cli/**, so I added the line there to. I then restarted the apache2 service.

I created a test file under /var/www/html/mongo.php

```
<?php

$m = new Mongo();
var_dump($m);exit;
```

When I browse to that page I get a 'This page isnt working; HTTP ERROR 500' message in Chrome. I have also tried **Mongodb();**, **MongoClient();**, **MongodbClient();**, **mongo();**, **mongodb();**, and **mongodbclient();**, but all to no avail.

Comment: Please share the mongo status... `sudo systemctl status mongod`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have also installed the mongodb php driver. Please confirm the php version first.

On Ubuntu you can just do:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mongodb
```

or the same for specific PHP version:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mongo
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mongodb
```

And then restart the service.

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

Comment: My version of PHP is PHP 7.2.17-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, but Ubuntu doesnt seem to have a version specific driver. I ran 'apt install php-mongodb' and then restarted Apache2, but still cannot load the page when i browse to it.
'systemctl status mongodb.service' shows it to be active (running)

Answer (score 0):

You should to try some of these

https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php

they should work fine with php7 + composer

Actually with composer is pretty easy(something like this):

```
`$ composer require mongodb/mongodb
 ./composer.json has been created
 Loading composer repositories with package information
 Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
   - Installing mongodb/mongodb (1.0.0)
     Downloading: 100%         

 Writing lock file
 Generating autoload files
```

Create a  File: test.php (in the same location where you ran composer)

```
<?php
 require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // include Composer's autoloader
 $client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
 $collection = $client->demo->beers;
 $result = $collection->insertOne( [ 'name' => 'Hinterland', 'brewery' => 'BrewDog' ] );
 echo "Inserted with Object ID '{$result->getInsertedId()}'";
 ?>
```

That should be enough